# Intercept HTTPS requests going to external server

Tags: angular

Is there any way to intercept HTTPS requests going to external server in angular.
What I did is I created HTTP interceptor and observable service that notifies app.component.
Inserted the interceptor service inside our module.
But I can see only HTTP requests going to backend are intercepted but not the HTTPS requests going to external server are not getting intercepted.

Will there is any special handling to intercept HTTPS requests going to external server?

My code:
my.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MyInterceptor } from './my.interceptor';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the difference between an external server and a backend?

Comment: What I mean is api calls going to any port on localhost are intercepted. But calls going to to external server via internet (say to https:facebook.com) are not getting intercepted.

Comment: how did u implemented Interceptor ? please share the code

Comment: Modified the question with code

Comment: Please share how you submit external requests

Comment: hit made via HttpClient (@angular/common/http) instance will be intercepted; this.http.post(url, requestDto) , http is instance of HttpClient

Comment: In my case, angulartics2piwiks which is a third part library which send the XMLHttpRequest to the piwik server. Is there anyway to intercept these requests?